# How do I resolve Exploit:HTML/IframeRef.R!MTB detected by Windows Security?

Tags: windows-10, security

I use Windows 10. Windows Defender detected an exploit in my system:

> Virus & threat protection
>
> Threats found. Start the recommended actions.
>
> Start actions
>
> See threat details

Where "Start actions" is a button and "See threat details" is a hyperlink.

If I click the "Start actions" button, the button vanishes, but nothing else seems to happen. The button reappears if I close and reopen the window.

If I click "See threat details", I go to a page labeled "Protection history" which lists two "severe" "recent items". The first one is described as "Threat found - action needed."

> Detected: Exploit:HTML/IframeRef.R!MTB
>
> Status: Active
>
> Active threats have not been remediated and are running on your device.
>
> ...
>
> Actions

Where "Actions" is a combo box which lets me choose "Quarantine" and "Remove". Neither choice seems do do anything.

The second item is described as "Remediation incomplete".

> Detected: Exploit:HTML/IframeRef.R!MTB
>
> Status: Failed
>
> This threat or app might not be completely remediated.
>
> ...

For this one, I have no combo box and no option to Quarantine or Remove.

Both items list an affected file, but I searched my drive and neither file seems to exist.

I have rebooted my computer. Nothing changes.

My questions:

Do I have a threat on my computer or not? And if so, how do I deal with it?

Windows Security is clearly buggy. Is there a known fix? Should I be ignoring Windows Security and relying on some other tool to keep my computer clean?

Comment: IMHO, Windows defender is in no way enough to protect you. You should look for some other free (or paid) antimalware. I personally use bitdefender free, and it works fine for me, except it takes quite some memory. You should look for a third party tool, and scan your entire system.

Comment: And the exploit seems to reside in the cache of browsers, which is cleared as soon as the program is closed. And as said [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Troubleshooting/comments/pe7dpw/exploithtmliframerefrmtb_detected_by_windows/hcc0w1g/) it might be just a false positive.